# Class 'Post' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member)

Tags: python, django

I am new in django and was following a tutorial to learn. This is the tutorial https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_templates/.

This is the **views.py** #  [views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vli5K.png)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: show your `models.py`

Comment: Please add the `Post` object from `models.py`. And have a look at the FAQ to properly format your question!

Comment: Django dynamically adds attributes to your Model instances, It would be quite common for IDE's to show such errors when using Django unless you add some plugin / extension for that. Ignore them. Found this plugin [pylint-django](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/) might help you.

Comment: Would be great to add a question add the end of your post to quickly see what should be answered